# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\products.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Im trying to build a shopping cart but i am getting this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\products.php on line 12

This is the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']==add){        
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
    } else {            
        $sql_s="SELECT * FROM tutorial WHERE id_product=[$id]";
        $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
        if (mysql_num_rows(&query_s)!=0){ 

        } else {
            $message="This ID is invalid!";
        }
  }
?>
```

## Product`s

```
<?php 
 if(isset($message)){
        echo"<h2>$message</h2>";
    }
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
      <?php
      $sql="SELECT * FROM tutorial ORDER BY name ASC";
      $query=mysql_query($sql);
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
         <td>&euro;<?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
         <td><a href="index.php?page=products$action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id_product']?>">Add to cart</a></td>
      </tr>
       <?php
          }
        ?>
 </table>
```

Can anyone help me it will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid character which is throwing off the parser.

```
if (mysql_num_rows(&query_s)!=0){
```

should be

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
```

Comment: Thanks but now im getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\products.php on line 51

Comment: You're probably missing a closing bracket somewhere

Comment: Know anything to this error perhaps?
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\products.php on line 12

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select